# Failing to publish changes to code on Sundays

Tags: front-end

Imagine you work for a financial services company that uses a pipeline to deploy new code to their customer-facing systems. Before any new code can be made available to customers, it must first go through a rigorous set of checks and scans. One check is that all of the unit tests that were written for the code pass. One Sunday, you get a call that there is a bug in some part of your system. You make a quick fix to your code but when you go to publish your change, you cannot! Your automated tests are failing. Many of your tests in the components that have to do with transferring money are failing because they cannot transfer money on a Weekend (banks are closed).
Does this show a problem in how your unit tests are written? If so, what is the problem?

Comment: This reads like an exam or homework question. We're happy to help you understand testing concepts, but we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: I disagree that this question is that bad. It is a software development process question that stabs right to the heart of what developers do: fix problems in production. Maybe not the best-researched question ever asked on this site, but a far cry from the worst. It's an interesting situation due to the business constraints of banks being closed on Sundays and needing to fix an urgent issue that is being blocked by automation.

Answer (score 7):

If the failing checks are truly unit tests (and not integration tests), then they are dependent upon the actual current date. What the test framework should provide is a way to override the current date so that the system under test is being exercised at a specific point in time. The system being tested would not reference the runtime's standard date/time object (e.g. `DateTime.Now` in C#), but some date/time object that is passed in and maintained by the system (e.g. `TestFrameworkCurrentDateTime`).

This issue also occurs often when dates and times are stored in UTC format and tests are run late at night in the US and the dates will be ahead one day.

For example, a test of funds transfers that only happen Monday-Friday should be run in a test environment which mocks the date as Monday-Friday. Additional tests can be also be added which attempt the funds transfers on a weekend and assert that the funds are not transferred (or some error condition).

**Bottom line**: a good unit test should pass regardless of when you run it.

Comment: Agreed, tests that fail because of what weekday it currently is are flawed. That being said we have a daily testrun that uses current date, it tends to find developers assumptions on number of days in months.

Comment: This isn't an either-or scenario. You should have unit tests which mock the date, you can also have a set of tests which use the current date. Both add value, but I'd be hesitant to call the second a unit test.

Comment: Just saying: Mocking the current date and time can be very, very difficult. Any third-party library could access the real date, and then you have two bits of code acting with very different times. Your best chance is running on a VM that allows creating a fake environment.

Answer (score 5):

I'll keep my answer short and sweet:

> Does this show a problem in how your unit tests are written?

Yes.

> If so, what is the problem?

They are not unit tests. Unit tests test a single unit of behavior in isolation. You are missing the "isolation" bit: they are not isolated from the clock.

Tests *in general*, not just unit tests, should be repeatable. If their results depend on the phase of the Moon (or the time of day, day of the week, hair color of the developer who made the last checkin, …), they are not repeatable.

If the behavior of the code depends on the current time, then the clock is a dependency that should be injected into the code. If you inject the clock as a dependency, you can run your unit tests with a mock clock, or rather with a set of mock clocks:

- One clock is simulating a week day,
- one is simulating a Sunday,
- one is simulating rolling over to a new day precisely at midnight,
- one is simulating rolling over to a new year precisely at New Year's Eve,
- one is simulating February, 29th,
- one is simulating changing from standard time to DST,
- one is simulating changing from DST to standard time,
- one is simulating a forward leap second (i.e. a minute with only 59 seconds),
- one is simulating a backward leap second (i.e. a minute with 61 seconds),
- and so on …

With your original tests, you could only test the behavior of leap years once every four years, and you could not even predict in advance when you can test the behavior of leap seconds. With a mock clock, all of that is trivial.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - are leap second tests still necessary?  I would have thought everyone was going to smear the leap second in their time servers in the future, so there won't be any continuity problem?

Comment: I work in an industry which chose TAI as its fundamental time standard precisely in order to avoid this question, so I'm probably the wrong person to ask :-D

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to manually bypass some of these checks and balances for emergency fixes. This incurs a *lot* of risk, especially for financial institutions. But then again, *not* fixing the problem also incurs a lot of risk.

The manual bypass can be a person logging in to whichever tool you use to automate deployments, and then push a button to start the deployment. Some tools allow you to specifically record approvals from other people (sometimes called "gatekeepers"). Worse case scenario, do it over e-mail and save the e-mails some place accessible by people at your organization. Saving them right in your automation tool would be ideal.

The "manual bypass" should absolutely **not** be a single person. If you need to deploy code on the weekend, and your automated tests cannot run, because external resources are closed for business reasons, then you and management need a way to bypass this and get the fix out to production. Something like this would probably need approval from someone pretty darn high up in the corporate hierarchy.

Get ready to be on a first name basis with the CEO. This might be a good thing or bad thing.

> Does this show a problem in how your unit tests are written? If so, what is the problem?

If your unit tests are failing because the banks are closed, then you have not written true unit tests. A unit test runs in-memory and operates on data in its own thread without reaching outside the thread.

More likely you have written **integration tests**. An integration test can certainly get data from outside the test itself, be it from a file, web service or database. There is nothing wrong with integration tests failing on Sunday because the banks are closed. The tests are not written incorrectly. In fact, it sounds like the tests are written correctly. You just need a way to bypass all of that automation for emergency fixes.

And get to know your CEO, because they should probably be the one to approve this blatant circumvention of extensive and well-planned checks and balances.

Comment: Sorry, but even for an integration test it is questionable if it should depend on the time and date when it is executed.

Comment: `You need a way to manually bypass some of these checks and balances for emergency fixes.` I completely disagree, and think this is very dangerous. When it comes to emergency fixes, automated checks are critically important in ensuring that the problem is not made worse. Emergency "fixes" rolled out while bypassing checks often cause more issues in my experience. I'm just as guilty as anyone else of thinking "it's a minor change, it should be fine."

Comment: @DocBrown: If your company does not control the outside system on which your integration tests depend, then there isn't much you can do. Especially if the business rules for your application and the outside system are heavily dependent upon day of the week or time of day. Some financial restrictions are not just a matter of practice. They are a matter of law or public policy. If the law says Thing X cannot be done on Sundays or outside certain hours, then that's how it is. Who's to say you don't have tests that run on Sundays ensuring Thing X *can't* be done?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: of course, such real world constraints can exist. But actually it is an indication that the tests run against a production system, or parts of it, and that might be pretty dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

If your team thinks CI/CD is the right approach for customer facing financial applications at a financial services company ... then your team is doing it wrong.  You all haven't been fired yet by your CFO or General Counsel?  Maybe *they're* the ones that should be fired.

Push-a-button-and-deploy-automatically-if-tests-pass is *not* the right solution in this case.  No matter how much the fanboys and paid trainers push it: CI/CD must be evaluated for suitability to your use case as much as any other tool.  And in this use case: They're totally inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this touches on a much broader problem of how many programmers habitually create direct dependencies on the current dates and times reported by the machine hardware, rather than fundamentally treating it as a kind of shared data.

Yes, it is true that this data is *normally* undergoing constant maintenance by the machine hardware, but for testing and debugging purposes the value should be capable of being maintained by a different mechanism, or set to a fixed value by hand.

Then it becomes obvious that if tests rely on date and time data, they should be testing for many different values of it, *not just the current value* (if indeed the current value is relevant *at all* in a testing context).